Log4j2 does not load custom ConsoleLogConverter and SocketLogResolverFactor plugins
I am trying to add two custom plugins to Log4j2: ConsoleLogConverter and `SocketLogResolverFactory'. However, Log4j2 does not load these plugins when the application is launched, despite the fact that they are correctly positioned and annotated.
I did this in principle in order to add masking to the logs, but so far I can't even test whether it works or not

Log4j2 version: 2.24
Java versions: 17
Framework: Spring Boot 3.3.2
Build system: Maven
I have tried both the log4j2.plugins file to create and the log4j2.component.properties file to create.
And at first Log4j2Plugins.dat was only in target, then I added it to be copied from target to resources, but my converter does not register

Here's what I've already checked:

Checked that the classes ConsoleLogConverter and SocketLogResolverFactory are in the correct package and annotated using `@Plugin'.
Made sure that the configuration file is log4j2.xml is loaded at startup.
Checked that the annotations @Plugin and @PluginFactory were imported from the correct Log4j packages.
Checked for conflicting versions of Log4j2 and other libraries in pom.xml .

log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace" monitorInterval="10">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="encProvider"/>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg_json%n"/>
            <Filters>
                <RegexFilter regex="(?i).*Authorization.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <RegexFilter regex="(?i).*getAccessToken.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <RegexFilter regex="(?i).*jwt.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Pom for log4j2
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-layout-template-json</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.mapstruct.binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>
                        src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties
                    </propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>
                        src/main/resources/liquibase/db_changelog_master.yaml
                    </changeLogFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-log4j2-plugins</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes/META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>Log4j2Plugins.dat</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

ConsoleLogConverter
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Plugin(name = "ConsoleLogConverter", category = CATEGORY)
@ConverterKeys({"msg_json"})
public class ConsoleLogConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter implements LogEventAppender {

    public ConsoleLogConverter() {
        super("Message", "message");
        System.out.println("ConsoleLogConverter loaded!");
    }

    public static ConsoleLogConverter newInstance(String[] options) {
        return new ConsoleLogConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
        appendAsJson(event, toAppendTo);
    }
}



my converter does not register

How are you determining this?
Log4j2 should be finding your plugin, if the plugin itself and the Log4j2Plugins.dat file are both on the classpath of your application when it is launched.

Log4j2 does not load these plugins when the application is launched

How are you launching your application?


at first Log4j2Plugins.dat was only in target, then I added it to be copied from target to resources

... that's not a thing, don't do that.
